# Import Data between two umbraco installations on different domains

Tags: import, content-management-system, umbraco

I have an umbraco installations on one domain: http://www.domain1.com/.
Is there some way (a package or other way) to import the data from this domain (when I say data, I mean the actual content inside the properties in the nodes) into another umbraco installation on a different domain, let's say http:/www.domain2.com/?

(I have, of course user permisiions for both installations).

The reason I am asking is that the first domain is a temporary domain which will hold the data without showing the frontend, while the second domain will hold the final data with the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the commercial Courier package. It allows you to migrate content in a few clicks. Unfortunately its $99 per domain, but it's way worth it if you have a localhost staging/dev environment that you're migrating content from since it runs from localhost for free. Subdomains are also included in the license.

http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx

Comment: Contact umbraco for a trial license.  They are very flexible and will give you a tailored trial license.